# error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::String>

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

I'm trying to install the node.js project and run
npm install
and got the error

> ../src/main.cc:137:89: error: no matching function for call to 'v8::Object::Set(v8::Local<v8::String>, Nan::imp::IntegerFactory<v8::Integer>::return_t)'

what is wrong with the project?

the full error is here https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hJGDfdrKB2/

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the package you are using doesn't support the version of Node you are running. Try running it under Node v8 and see if that corrects the problem. If it does let the package maintainer know it needs updating.

Plasma

Comment: I love the way we can't tell what version of node we need for a given project. `npm` sure doesn't like package managers, or maintainers or the users.

Answer (score 0):

downgrading to nodejs-10, worked for me.
Hope this will help.